# AWS SageMaker EndPoint returns 415

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, awsdeploy

I have trained a multiclass classification model on the wine quality dataset and I have deployed the model.
After deploying the model I got EndPoint URL like:

https://runtime.sagemaker.region.amazonaws.com/endpoints/experiment/invocations

And I am invoking the URL after passing AWS credentials and body like:

`{
  "instances": [7.4,0.7,0,1.9,0.076,11,34,0.9978,3.51,0.56,9.4]
}`

But I am getting below error:

`{
    "ErrorCode": "CLIENT_ERROR_FROM_MODEL",
    "LogStreamArn": "",
    "OriginalMessage": "'application/json' is an unsupported content type.",
    "OriginalStatusCode": 415
}`

I tried looking for the trace logs in the cloud watch but no traces there as well. Anyone could guide me on this?

I have trained a model using Sage Maker Studion.

Answer (score 0):

The message "'application/json' is an unsupported content type." seems to show your issue. Most likely your inference container does not support JSON content type, so you will need to use a content type that the container supports.